# How do I re-authorize Quicktime Player to use the microphone when once it has been denied?

Tags: audio, mojave, usb, quicktime, microphone

I wanted to use a USB audio input to record a video, and got something I've never seen before having done this 100 times; it asked "Authorize Quicktime to use the microphone?" I clicked no, because I didn't want it to use the internal mic, I wanted it to use a USB input.  Now, it won't let me get rid of the denial.  I've quit QT, quit & reopened it twice and it still won't let me choose ANY input source. It still says it doesn't have access to the microphone.  Is this a new Mojave 10.14.2 bug or what?  How the heck do I get out of this?  Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

Go to **System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Privacy > Microphone**, unlock the preference pane by clicking the padlock symbol at the bottom left of the window and tick "QuickTime Player.app", which should be listed without a tick mark in its checkbox.

If QuickTime Player.app is missing, you should be able to reset all decisions you made for the various applications that asked for access to your Microphone by quitting System Preferences, opening Terminal (to be found in /Applications/Utilities/, or search via Spotlight) and running the following command:

```
tccutil reset Microphone
```

...then press <kbd>enter</kbd>.

This should clear all applications from the Microphone section and after launching QuickTime Player, it should ask for permission to the microphone all over again.

Comment: It's noteworthy that this erases all of the apps that have already requested access, and depending on the logic of the app, they might not request access again. Use with caution.

Comment: @ChaimEliyah I added an [answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/384295/18101) that avoids wiping out microphone permissions for other apps.

Comment: It erased all the microphone permission. But when I start QuickTime player  > screen recording(or audio recording) it doesn't ask permission.

Answer (score 5):

This [new requirement to authorize Microphone](https://support.apple.com/en-ca/guide/mac-help/mchla1b1e1fe/10.14/mac/10.14) was added in macOS Mojave (10.14).

The [answer from Redarm](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/345749/18101) is very good, and the best answer for people using macOS Mojave (10.14). But there is a slightly better option for people using macOS Catalina (10.15) or newer. This will reset the privacy settings for QuickTime Player only, without affecting microphone permission settings for other applications.

```
tccutil reset Microphone com.apple.QuickTimePlayerX
```

Note that you **must** quit and restart QuickTime Player after running this command.

Answer (score 1):

For me QuickTime was not sharing my iphone screen as well. My QuickTime started showing this warning:

> can not use Vaibhav's iphone. This app is not authorized to use Vaibhav's iphone quicktime

What I did:
Go to System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Privacy and follow these steps:
[image]

---

[image]